# Running PS1 as script; issues in Windows 8

Tags: powershell, runas

I have a script that I commonly run via a shortcut, and in Windows 8 and above I have to right click Run as Administrator for everything to work right. This is true even when I am logged in as an Administrator. However, I also want to automate this a couple different ways, including Remoting, SCCM/ZenWorks/Case, Scheduled tasks etc. So far as I can tell, there is no way to "Run as Administrator" in those cases. So, is there some setting in Windows 8 that removes the need for Run as Administrator, or a way to RaA with non manual mechanisms, or...?

Comment: If you are asking if you can bypass the UAC prompt dynamically, the answer is no. That prompt is there for a reason. (If it were possible to programmatically bypass, then all malware would do it.)

Comment: So, it is not possible to use PowerShell to automate program installs after Windows 7? That seems a little odd. The entire point of PowerShell is management of machines. Color me confused.

Comment: Automation of tasks that require administrative privilege still require administrative privilege. PowerShell doesn't somehow let you magically bypass security requirements.

Comment: Indeed, but when LOGGED IN as an administrator, and running an SCCM job in that context, I would expect PowerShell to work. If someone has access to my admin account I am screwed, and stopping PS from working isn't going to help me. Especially not when BAT and VBS files will still run. It's just an annoyance. And, it seems to me, there is almost certainly a registry setting somewhere, that will allow Win 8 and above to work like Win 7, where logging in as an admin is all that is needed, no right click Run As silliness required.

Comment: I think we're talking about some different concepts. Your question seems more suited to serverfault rather than here (so is for programming questions).

Comment: Win7 and win8.x have the same UAC settings, if you were not using RunAs then, it probably means UAC was disabled on those systems. See more here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-user-account-control-settings#1TC=windows-7 Look at the last setting (disabling) at the bottom.

Comment: It is not recommended to disable UAC. UAC has a very good design and guiding principle and it was created for a very good reason.

Comment: FWIW, I am not disabling UAC, I have it set at Default (1 step down) for my limited use Admin account, and at full for users. In Windows 7 everything works fine, and Run as Administrator is not required. In Windows 8, some things don't work without Run as Administrator. And since the stuff that doesn't work is code, I figured this was the place to address it. But, I'll try ServerVault too. Thanks!

Comment: The reason UAC was created is home users using their administrator account for everything. UAC has no business in a professionally managed environment.

Comment: Ansgar, I mostly agree with you. But, having met users in the Architectural space (WeatherBug, sure, I'll install that! Anna Kournikova naked, what's not to like!) I do like to keep it on for users. But when logged in as an admin, UAC is just stupid. My next test is to see if I can kill UAC just for the admin user. That may solve the problem. Or it may just be that Windows 8 sucks. That seems more likely to me. Hopefully Windows 10 is rid of much of the Balmer stink.

Comment: @Gordon UAC is a system setting, not a per-user setting. What you can do to make it less annoying while still leaving it enabled is to disable prompting for members of the "Administrators" group and set shortcuts to programs that require admin privileges to always run "as Admin". The former is done in the local policies (`secpol.msc`) under *Security Options*, the latter in the properties of the shortcuts under *Advanced*.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with @AnsgarWiechers that UAC has no business in a professional environment. There are good reasons not to disable it, and it does not impede business when you manage systems correctly (IMO).

Comment: So, two things at play perhaps. First, if I have a secure admin only account, and a signed PS1 file, there should NEVER be a requirement for Run as Administrator that then removes SCCM as the means of running said script. i have HUNDREDS of machines this needs run on. Forcing a manual process is just stupid, and even Balmer's MS wasn't that stupid. So, gotta be a solution. Second, the key is that certain tasks don't work. For example, in Windows 7 I can use Copy-Item to copy into Program Files without trouble.

Comment: But (default install) of Windows 8 requires right click Run As Administrator or it throws a permissions error. And UAC level seems not to matter. So, I have to believe there is a way to get SCCM, PowerShell & Windows 8 to play together. Needing to remote in to each machine and kick it off manually is just ridiculous.

Comment: We run automated stuff all the time that doesn't stop at the UAC prompt. The reason is that the system process that runs the tasks is elevated already. Your last sentence is proof IMO that you don't seem to understand how this works. Post in ServerFault. This is not a programming question.